# Aggregation on subdocuments with unknown key names

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents with the following structure:

```
"_id" : "20130104/activity",
"hourly" : {
    "0" : {
        "activity1" : 25,
        "activity2" : 10
    },
    "1" : {
        "activity1" : 25,
        "activity2" : 10,
        "activity3" : 5
    },
    "2" : {
        "activity1" : 25,
        "activity2" : 10,
        "activity3" : 5
    }
    }
```

I would like to be able to aggregate this data to be able to generate monthly and daily statistics like the document shown here:

```
"date" : "20130104",
"total" : {
        "activity1" : 75,
        "activity2" : 30,
        "activity3" : 10
          }
```

My problem is that i do not know the key names in the hourly subdocument beforehand - which makes using the aggregate framework quite hard. (or maybe i just misunderstood something).

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a maximum of 24 elements per `hourly` array?

Comment: Yes. (it is not a array)

Answer (score 0):

map reduce can be used here to calculate the reporting data , as you do not need to know the name of the key. One another approach is as we have 24 hours a day , you can always have a document with 24 hours key and then easily you can use the aggregation framework . Even this approach will give you performance boost up also and it is common pattern

Comment: My document already has 24 hours keys, could you give a short example  on how to use the aggregation framework with this examples?